# Give warning if folder contains more than one file type using RegExp

Tags: regex

Using RegExp to search a folder for file types held in an Array.

How can I show a fail if the folder contains more than one different file type but it is perfectly OK to have multiple of the same file type in the folder.

Here's my code:

```
var AllowedFileTypes = ["orf", "tif", "tiff", "jpg", "jpeg"];
var regex = new RegExp('.+\.(?:' + AllowedFileTypes.join('|')+ ')$','i');
fileList = inputFolder.getFiles(regex);
```

Thanks

Comment: First things first: use `\\.` instead of `\.` in the string pattern. What is a string that should produce a warning?

Comment: OK, I'll do that but can you shed some light on what this will do?

Comment: `\.` is ok on single quoted strings. And just do the join yourself, no need to excersize coding skills.

Comment: OK thanks, this is a completely new area for me so do not know how to do join

Comment: @1cm69: Look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fxwjewcb/) and mind my first comment.

Comment: EXAMPLE: If 'inputFolder' contains more than one string from Array 'AllowedFileTypes' then user should be alerted - if 'inputFolder' contains more than file of just one file type from 'AllowedFileTypes' Array then this is OK

Comment: EXAMPLE: if(fileList == jpg){alert('all good')} but if(fileList == jpg && orf || tif){alert('not good')} etc....